# How to use mouseEvent on QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class that inherits `QGraphicsView` and I want to add `mousePressEvent` on this class.
How can I do that?

This is my function:

```
void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
    cards[0]->setPos(event->pos());
    scene->addItem(cards[0]);
}
```

Where `cards[0]` is a `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It's very difficult to help unless you show some relevant code and describe the problem in a bit more detail.

Comment: @G.M. this is my code!

Comment: Can you provide code in which you add QGraphicsPixmapItem (cards[0]) to scene?

Comment: @KirillChernikov sure , see my code again

Comment: It's strange that you add item to the scene every time when mouse pressed. Can you try to add item not in mousePressEvent? Maybe when you do initialization step?

Comment: @KirillChernikov I need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the wrong parameter type in your `mousePressEvent` function.

In `QGraphicsView` you have to use `mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)` and not `mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*)`. The `mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*)` is a method of `QGraphicsScene`, not of `QGraphicsView`.